# Apache Camel multipart route

Tags: java, file-upload, apache-camel, multipartform-data

I'm trying to route a file to HTTP file upload API via Apache Camel. But I'm getting following exception

```
org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity@71ef4d4f of type: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity on: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileMessage@7e693963. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity@71ef4d4f. Exchange[org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileMessage@7e693963]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity@71ef4d4f]
```

Can anyone help here?
Following is what I tried so far

My fileupload controller method mapped with the URL api/fileupload expects a `MultipartHttpServletRequest`

MyCamelRouter.java

```
public class MyCamelRouter extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file:C:/src")
        .process(new MyProcessor())
        .log("POST ${header.CamelFileName} to /upload")
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("multipart/form-data"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
        .to("http:localhost:8080/sampleUploader/api/fileupload")
        .log("HTTP response status: ${header.CamelHttpResponseCode}")
        .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "HTTP response body:\n${body}");
}
```

}

and in MyProcessor.java

```
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        File filetoUpload = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
        String fileName = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, String.class);

        MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entity.addTextBody("fileName", fileName);
        entity.addBinaryBody("file", new File(filePath));

        exchange.getOut().setBody(entity.build());  
    }
```

}

[This](http://hilton.org.uk/blog/camel-multipart-form-data) is the link I followed for this(Scala DSL)

Comment: @Panchitoboy Yes I managed to POST the request externally with  HTTPClient. Thanks a lot for your help...

Answer (score 4):

The message is clear when it say that you need an InputStream

The method build returns an HttpEntity.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html

You can try with the method getContent()

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html?is-external=true

Try to change your:

```
exchange.getOut().setBody(entity.build());
```

to:

```
exchange.getOut().setBody(entity.build().getContent());
```

UPDATE

After your comment the other thing you can do is:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
entity.build().writeTo(out);
InputStream  inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
exchange.getOut().setBody(inputStream);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion but I'm getting the following Exception  `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Multipart form entity does not implement #getContent()`   Is there any other way?

Comment: Now I'm able to send the request to the API. But I think it does not contain the actual file. Please see the API implementation below
 `public void handleFileUpload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
        Iterator<String> itrator = request.getFileNames();
        MultipartFile multipartFile = request.getFile(itrator.next());
    }`  
When the request receives here In this case `itrator` gives no files to iterate and so I'm unable to get the files in my server. What can I do here? Please help

Comment: I think is the way that you are building your MultipartEntityBuilder. Try to see is that works without Camel: There is a example here on how use it: http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-multipart-upload