# Camel send multipart/form-data request

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have an app, that sends a multipart/form-data & an app that recieves multipart/form-data request.

Processing in reciever:

```
    InputStreamCache postBody = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStreamCache.class);
    MultipartUploadContext mux = new MultipartUploadContext(postBody, exchange.getIn().getHeader("Content-Type",String.class));
    Map<String,Object> params = mux.parseRequest();
```

Parsing a request, send from Postman/Swagger works fine.
I have troubles integrating my camel-sender with my camel reciever.

Here is the sender route:

```
from("direct:uploadFileToRest").routeId("uploadFileToRest").
    process("uploadFileRequestProcessor").
    setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("POST")).
    setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("multipart/form-data")).
    to("myrecieverapp/full_upload").
    id("fileUploadRestSending").
    log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "RESPONSE BODY ${body}").
end();
```

The sender processor:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder
                .create()
                .addTextBody("name", "SomeName")
                .addBinaryBody("content", array_with_byte_content_here);
exchange.getOut().setBody(multipartEntityBuilder.build());
```

The following error occures:

```
 No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity@35315261 of type: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity on: Message[ID-VRN26-1529401997491-0-3]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity@35315261.
```

After looking up for the same issue, I found up a recommendation to change out body to:

```
 exchange.getOut().setBody(multipartEntityBuilder.build().getContent());
```

However,it causes issues on reciever side:

```
the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found\r\n\tat org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:990)\r\n\tat org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:310)\r\n\tat org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:334)\r\n\tat ru.cinimex.abb.fileuploader.util.MultipartUploadContext.parseRequest(MultipartUploadContext.java:29)\r\n\tat ru.cinimex.abb.fileuploader.camel.processors.ValidateFullUploadRequestProcessor.process(ValidateFullUploadRequestProcessor.java:33)\r\n\tat org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)\r\n\tat org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)\r\n\tat
```

I've read theese posts:

http://hilton.org.uk/blog/camel-multipart-form-data

[Apache Camel multipart route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815792/apache-camel-multipart-route)

but couldn't find a solution

Camel version: org.apache.camel:camel-cxf:2.21.0.000033-fuse-000001-redhat-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `Content-Type` header with correct boundary, which is generated in `MultipartEntityBuilder`. Modify your sender processor to set this header.

```
HttpEntity resultEntity = multipartEntityBuilder.build();
exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, resultEntity.getContentType().getValue());
exchange.getOut().setBody(resultEntity.getContent());
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the particilar issue. I was able to parse to multipart data on the reciever side. But I face another problem: Content length is too long: 565611 when sending a request with proper content.

Comment: For future reference. If you found this anwer and you are using `camel-http4` component for making `POST` multipart request, there is simplier way, without setting `ContentType` header manually. See this answer for details: [Apache Camel - Multipart File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51225444/8576169)